# Accidentally started uninstalling Node and cancelled it. Should I install it again?

Tags: node.js

I was uninstalling something and I accidentally started uninstalling node_modules folder. I cancelled it almost immediately. Looks like I emptied my recycle bin too later on without realizing what I was doing. I still see the node_modules folder and I see the packages in it. But I think it did delete some things in there..can't be sure. Do you suggest I install node again?
That will require getting my hands dirty in many ways with regards to the code repo I have!
Thanks!

Comment: There's a mistake in my first line...I meant to say I started uninstalling NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

If you reinstall node it will remove old version and reinstall application.